# Little correction to email regular expression

Tags: regex

This my expression

```
(\w+\.)*\w+\s*(@|\({1}\s*at\s*\){1}|\s+at\s+){1}\s*(\S{2,3}\.)?(\w+)(\s*dot\s*|\s*\.*\s*)(com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum|ru)\b
```

gives **ombe@cs.name.edu** from **l@ombe@cs.name.edu** which is wrong

I need to exclude **l@ombe@cs.name.edu** from possible variants

I have developed this regex to extract emails out of a variety of obfuscated strings rather than validate, as a part of my home assignment. Stuck on **l@ombe@cs.name.edu** test.

Would you please help me?

**Redefenition:**

Expression:

```
(\w+)@(\w+)\.name\.edu
```

2 strings:

- name@name1@cs.name.edu
- name2@cs.name.edu

As a result a get:

*name1@cs.name.edu* and *name2@cs.name.edu*

1 part mustn't be included at all.

Comment: What if somebody has a '.im' address, or one belonging to any other TLD which you have not listed?

Comment: It's not a problem, this is just simplistic approach, which I will replace afterwards

Comment: The regular expression for email is *very* complicated. Look at [this question, and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses)

Comment: That is a very good example of validation. But for my learning home assignment I have developed a regex to **extract** emails out of a variety of obfuscated strings

Comment: I see that now. You also want to pick out words like 'at', 'dot' and understand what they mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt?)**

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Comment: Thank you, good example. I have developed this regex to **extract** emails out of a variety of obfuscated strings rather than validate, as a part of my home assignment. Stuck on l@ombe@cs.name.edu test.

Answer (score 0):

You can anchor a regular expression to the start and end of the string with ^ and $.
This forces the entire string to be matched, instead of only a part of it.

In your case:

```
^(\w+\.)*\w+\s*(@|\({1}\s*at\s*\){1}|\s+at\s+){1}\s*(\S{2,3}\.)?(\w+)(\s*dot\s*|\s*\.*\s*)(com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum|ru)\b$
```

Comment: This doesn't work. For example, \b in the end excludes "Talk at Supercomputing" from variants. but somehow I fail to figure out an expression for the start of the string